# DiscordJS (Node) Sending PM to user and await reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get my bot to send a user a private message when a user types a command, and then wait for a reply to the private message.

Expected flow:

- Jim types: `!auth`
- bot sends Jim a private message
- Jim replies to the message with `blablabla`
- Bot sees the `blablabla` reply and outputs to terminal => `console.log( replyResponse );`

I have tried numerous examples I have found from here and in the docs but none of them works.

```js
message.author.send('test').then(function () {
  message.channel
    .awaitMessages((response) => message.content, {
      max: 1,
      time: 300000000,
      errors: ['time'],
    })
    .then((collected) => {
      message.author.send(`you replied: ${collected.first().content}`);
    })
    .catch(function () {
      return;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.author.send('test')` returns the sent message so you should use that returned message to set up a message collector. At the moment, you're using `message.channel.awaitMessages` and that waits for messages in the channel where the user sent the `!auth` message, not the one where the bot sent a response.

Check out the working code below. It uses async-await, so make sure that the parent function is an `async` function. I used [`createMessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector) instead of [`awaitMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) as I think it's more readable.

```js
try {
  // wait for the message to be sent
  let sent = await message.author.send('test');
  // set up a collector in the DM channel
  let collector = sent.channel.createMessageCollector({
    max: 1,
    time: 30 * 1000,
  });

  // fires when a message is collected
  collector.on('collect', (collected) => {
    collected.reply(`✅ You replied: _"${collected.content}"_`);
  });

  // fires when we stopped collecting messages
  collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
    sent.reply(`I'm no longer collecting messages. Reason: ${reason}`);
  });
} catch {
  // send a message when the user doesn't accept DMs
  message.reply(`❌ It seems I can't send you a private message...`);
}
```

[image]

Make sure, you don't forget to enable the `DIRECT_MESSAGES` intents. For example:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
  ],
});
```